# Cannot download node-sqlite3@4.2.0 - node-pre-gyp ERROR Tried to download(403) Access Denied - node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I've been trying to download `sqlite3@4.2.0`, however it's been giving me an error. Here are the logs when trying to run `npm install`:

```
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future

> sqlite3@4.2.0 install /Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v83-darwin-arm64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@14.17.0 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node /Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node" "/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/bin/node /Users/crypthusiast0/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/crypthusiast0/Dev/nodejs/auction-flipper/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN node-auction-flipper@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN node-auction-flipper@0.1.0 license should be a valid SPDX license expression

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@4.2.0 install: `node - pre - gyp install--fallback - to - build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/crypthusiast0/.npm/_logs/2021-06-10T21_46_58_721Z-debug.log
```

I looked back at the logs to see that https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v83-darwin-arm64.tar.gz is probably the main cause of this because if you actually go to the link, it gives you this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>Q0JKD48B1117QG62</RequestId>
<HostId>0tR6ildiySR62EjZI4DwfeVbxSFIOClQUiIyMCySpd/lficx42uEJ2YU94GtQQvMnF4EENuWH/0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I'n not entirely sure how to fix this because I'm not very experienced with Node.js/NPM and installing modules, however I do need `node-sqlite3` specifically version `4.2.0` because one of my VSCode extensions relies on it. I have found the github repo of `node-sqlite` and the `4.2.0` source code. Is there any way to fix this or compile the module from source? Maybe could it be because it's not supported on my node version/os? I had this working before so I'm not sure.

I'm on a MacBook Air M1 (ARM) running node version v16.3.0 and npm version v7.16.0.

Comment: please provide the the full error when you try to install it with npm

Comment: also can you tell us the version of nodejs you are using

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Yea its in the post, I managed to fix the issue though, however the VSCode extension still doesn't work so I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: yep .. i didn't see it, i think i need some rest for now, i updated the answer you need  either use a correct version of nodejs or use  npm to directlly install  `node-sqlite3` from github

Comment: can i ask what's the name of this extension? or could it be that you are developing one ?

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Actually I just fixed the issue. Seems like it was trying to install SQLite3 on a v14.17.0 instead of v16.3.0, just deleted the nvm folder and it worked. By the way, if you're still wondering, the extension is called SQLTools, and it requires another extension for SQLite support called SQLTools SQLite.

Comment: Great .. you need to pay attention when using nvm to which version of node you're using and make sure it's the correct one. I will take a look at the extension later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is not helpful in my case. Also, I found that simply using `yarn` instead of `npm` solves the issues mentioned by the other answer.

However, that answer does not address the main issue:

> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-*******.tar.gz

> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found

### TL;DR

For me, upgrading to [latest `sqlite3`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) (e.g. via `yarn add "sqlite3@^5"` (NOTE: [this command does not work properly in powershell](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3270))) fixes this issue. The reason for that is: it finds the pre-built binaries for this version just fine.

If you (absolutely) NEED to use an older version, you will have to make sure, the local compilation succeeds, as explained below.

In addition to that, you also want to make sure, you have a somewhat recent version of `node` installed, because often times, pre-built binaries are commonly not provided for out-of-date Node versions (check `node -v`; recommendation: use [volta](https://volta.sh/) to manage your node version).

Warning: Of course, those pre-built binaries might also be removed by the package author in the near fututure. Hopefully, they will at least replace them with a newer version, and not just take them offline entirely.

### Explanation

The error message above indicates that `gyp` was not able to download the **system-specific** pre-built binaries (which is very different from the `npm` package). Because it cannot find the pre-built binaries, it would try to compile them locally, which is always messy and can easily go wrong.

- Q: Why can it not find the pre-built binaries?

  - A: Pre-built binaries are not so easy to manage because you need a lot more different versions of them than just the version of the `npm` package they are for. Usually, you need one for each major version of the `npm` package + version of node + operating system + [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instruction_set_architectures#Instruction_sets) (e.g. ARM 32bit vs. x86 64bit etc.). It appears that, for some reason, Mapbox decided not to store those pre-built binaries for the long haul. I am sure they were there in the past, but for version 4.2.0 (and possibly many other versions), they are gone now.
  - They might only keep all those different binaries for the latest major version of their `npm` package and wipe old versions to save storage space. I have not found any documentation on that [on their repo](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3).
- Q: What happens if it cannot download the pre-built binaries?

  - A: Things get very messy. Instead of a short download, it tries to compile them *on your system*, involving a complex labyrinth of system-level dependencies. For example:

    - In case of the OP, that compilation failed due to:

      > gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
    - In my case, it failed because (on Windows), I did not have `VS 2017` (nor its redistributables) installed.
  - In general, local compilation firstly requires `node-gyp` to play along, and then you also need `python` and a system-specific C++ compiler. If you Google a little, you will find many stories of people succeeding (and failing) to get such local compilation to work. It is possible to aim for local compilation, but getting the pre-built binaries makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Using yarn and updating to the latest version of node-sqlite3 may resolve the issue of installing node-sqlite3 in your case , **But the thing is if you read the Q carefully he specified that he needs `node-sqlite3 version 4.2.0`  so i think this is the easiest way to install that specific version of node-sqlite3  in his case**

Comment: Nice explanation about `gyp` and the pre-built binaries btw

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui It does not solve the problem though. If you want to solve the problem using `4.2.0` on their machine, and there are no pre-built binaries available, one needs to tackle the OP's system-specific compilation problems, i.e. `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`. The other answer does not explain how to solve that.

Comment: @WaLidLamRaoui Thanks for the feedback. I added an explanation in case someone needs to target a specific version.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer with explanation. It really helped me.

Comment: @Domi, I am having the same issue with `gc-stats` what do I need to do? just change node versions until I find the right one for this package?

Comment: @FernandoSantiago Sounds like `gc-stats` has a dependency on `sqlite`? You can maybe try to manually override the indirect dependency to point to a `sqlite` version that has pre-built binaries.

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the errors try the following :

- clean the npm cache

  ```
   npm cache clean
  ```
- run npm install and see if it's working

  ```
   npm install
  ```

And since you didn't tell us wich version of node you are using it maybe related to not using a correct version of node it mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3/v/4.2.0) that `node-sqlite3` v4.2.0 works with :

- Node.js v4.x, v6.x, v8.x, v10.x, v11.x, v12.x and v13.x.

so you may consider using the correct version of nodejs

---

### **Alternatively**

If you're trying to install `node-sqlite3 v4.2.0` manually from the source code. it's actually possible as mentioned here on the npm [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install). Just make sure you are downloading the tarball file not the zip file one, in your case it should be this [one](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.0.tar.gz)

Move the tarball where it should be, then simply run the following :

```
npm install node-sqlite3-4.2.0.tar.gz
```

Or even simpler :

```
npm install https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Latest sqlite3 package now supports Apple ARM (M1, M2).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine downgrading node from 14 to 12.